# Optimize way to fetch data from multiple tables in mysqli PHP

Tags: php, android, mysqli, api-design

Right now I am learning to write an android api in php for some CRUD operation.

I am able fetch data from the database without any issue.

Now I want to fetch 200, 500 and 600 records from three different tables.
At the end I am going to show it the UI by grouping them at their appropriate position.

My question is, should I write **multiple php files for fetching the records from each table** and send it back to the user separately (obviously I have call the api separately one after the another from the app after getting the response of each of the previous call).

OR

Only **one php file where I will fetch all the records from the three tables** and send it back to the user in one shot.

*I am returning the data in json format.*

Please help in figuring out which one of the above method should I use and its advantage or disadvantage if any..

Comment: Are you going to display 200, 500 or 600 records on the UI at the same time? How will that affect your app being user friendly?

Comment: If the records are linked, have you thought about using sql joins?

Comment: @Hallur  10 records of 1st table is linked to 25 records from 2nd table and 30 records from 3rd one. So, this 10+25+30= 65 records of information will be shown in one view and so on.. They are not exactly linked. But they are somehow related according to the information that I have to show it in the UI

Comment: @EmmanuelO They are not exactly linked. But they are somehow related according to the information that I have to show it in the UI